# Paso de valores Aplicacion web Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

Tengo una aplicación web con un pequeño formulario que debe completar el usuario.
una de las partes es el nombre de la Empresa. 
tengo dos clases creadas, unas con los datos del formulario y otro con datos de las entidades.
la idea es que seleccione de una pagina razor la Empresa y este dato vuelque en el formulario de solicitud.
Una vez seleccionada la empresa tengo el siguiente botón que debe enviar ese dato al formulario.

```
   <a asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-page="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Selecionar</a>
```

el Id lo manda correctamente, pero a la hora de recibirlo no me fuciona. Este es el codigo de Create.cshtml.cs que es el que debe recibir ese dato.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;

}


[BindProperty]
public Peticion Peticion { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public Entidades Entidades { get; set; }
[TempData]
public String Mensaje { get; set; }
public async Task OnGet(int Id)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
        Entidades = await _db.Entidades.FindAsync(Id);

    var PeticionDesdeDB = await _db.Entidades.FindAsync(Entidades.Id);

}

}
```

el id viene correcto pero no lo incluye en mi Input. Creo que es por que el html no lo recibe bien. Mi html es

```
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="Entidades.Id" />
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Entidades.Id" />
        <div class="jumbotron text-center p-3 mb-2 shadow mb-5 text-success rounded rounded-pill border">Información del cliente</div>
        <!--  <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"> </div>-->
        <div class="container" style="padding:30px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label asp-for="Peticion.NombreEntidad"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4">

                        <input asp-for="Peticion.NombreEntidad" class="form-control" />


                    </div>
```

Entiendo que es por que el input es de la clase petición y el dato que viene es de la clase Entidades, pero no se como hacerlo o si hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo.
gracias

Comment: puedes remormular tu pregunta no se entiende.

Comment: Simplemente quiero seleccionar en una pagina un valor, EntidadA por ejemplo y que ese dato lo introduzca en otra pagina, donde hay un imput vacio.